# What does this Valgrind output mean?

Tags: c++, valgrind

So I'm writing this `C++` program and I've narrowed down my memory leaks by quite a bit thank to `valgrind`. But I still have a large chunk of leaks to go. But my `valgrind` output isn't making any sense:

```
9,512 (7,104 direct, 2,408 indirect) bytes in 148 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 4 of 4

==2638==    at 0x402B9B4: operator new(unsigned int) (in /usr/lib/valgrind
/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==2638==    by 0x804C8AD: __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::vector<plate, std::allocator<plate> > >::allocate(unsigned int, void const*) (in /home/.../program)
==2638==    by 0x804C2FF: std::_Vector_base<std::vector<plate, std::allocator<plate> >, std::allocator<std::vector<plate, std::allocator<plate> > > >::_M_allocate(unsigned int) (in /home/.../program)
==2638==    by 0x804B7F7: std::vector<std::vector<plate, std::allocator<plate> >, std::allocator<std::vector<plate, std::allocator<plate> > > >::_M_insert_aux(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::vector<plate, std::allocator<plate> >*, std::vector<std::vector<plate, std::allocator<plate> >, std::allocator<std::vector<plate, std::allocator<plate> > > > >, std::vector<plate, std::allocator<plate> > const&) (in /home/.../program)
==2638==    by 0x804AF48: std::vector<std::vector<plate, std::allocator<plate> >, std::allocator<std::vector<plate, std::allocator<plate> > > >::push_back(std::vector<plate, std::allocator<plate> > const&) (in /home/.../program)
==2638==    by 0x804A57C: hanoi_object::hanoi_object(hanoi_object const&) (in /home/.../program)
==2638==    by 0x804A6C9: hanoi_object::getMoves() const (in /home/.../program)
==2638==    by 0x8048FE1: Solver::solve(std::Config*, std::Config*) (in /home/.../program)
==2638==    by 0x804A0D3: main (in /home/.../program)
```

#### Program abstract~ skip if you want.

My program is basically a rudimentary Hanoi puzzle solver using a breadth first search algorithm to solve. Now, I represent the puzzle itself by a double vector of plate objects (`vector< vector< plate > >`), where plate is but a simple class that holds one integer value, the weight or size of the disk. A class called `hanoi_object` is responsible for collecting, representing, moving and maintaining these objects. A solver class will later allocate various `hanoi_objects` on the heap and delete it if it's not what we're looking for.

According to `valgrind` it looks like it's having issues with my double vector of plate objects. But why? It's a class that contains a simple `int` value and I never allocate any plate objects on the heap. Does allocating the handler/controller object (`hanoi_object`) on the heap also allocate my double vector plate object or something?

Here's the destructor:

```
hanoi_object::~hanoi_object(){
    for(int i=0; i<pegs_.size(); i++){
        pegs_[i].clear();
    }
    pegs_.clear();
}
```

And the copy constructor:

```
hanoi_object::hanoi_object(const hanoi_object& hanoi_object){
    for(int i = 0; i < hanoi_object.pegs_.size(); i++){
        vector<plate> PL;
        for(int j = 0; j < hanoi_object.pegs_[i].size(); j++){
            plate somePlate(hanoi_object.pegs_[i][j].getWeight());
            PL.push_back(somePlate);
        }
        pegs_.push_back(PL);
    }
}
```

All allocations in the hanoi_object are in other functions and I've triple checked to make sure that those are either deleted or passed to another class.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your copy constructor `hanoi_object::hanoi_object(hanoi_object const&)` is allocating something (probably with `new`) which your destructor is not freeing (with `delete`).  It looks like it is the double vector of `plate`s.  Much more than that, we can't say without seeing the code for the copy constructor and the destructor.

---

The boundary between 'system' and 'user' functions in the trace is at:

- `std::vector<std::vector<plate, std::allocator<plate> >, std::allocator<std::vector<plate, std::allocator<plate> > > >
  ::push_back(std::vector<plate, std::allocator<plate> > const&)`
- `hanoi_object::hanoi_object(hanoi_object const&)`

This indicates to me that one of the two `push_back` calls in the copy constructor is doing the damage.  Given the type information, I think it is the second such call:

```
pegs_.push_back(PL);
```

Formally, we can't tell from the information given whether `pegs_` is a global variable or a class member (yes, I know; it is probably a class member, but we can't be sure since you've not shown us even an outline of the class definition).

In the destructor, you [`clear`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/clear/) the `pegs_` variable.  This removes and destroys all the elements in the vector; it does not free the vector itself.

Comment: I added in the functions above. I highly doubt it's that. Although later on in the program I allocate the current state of the object doing "hanoi_object* thisConfig = new hanoi_object(*this);" Then as time goes on I do "delete thisConfig". Would this process leave behind an allocated double vector of plates on the heap somewhere?

Comment: @user2326106: If you don't delete all of those objects you create with `new`, and one contains a vector, then that vector will indeed never be destroyed. And if you're relying on manual deletion, then you're quite likely not to delete everything. As much as possible, avoid using `new`; when you really must, manage the dynamic objects with smart pointers.

Answer (score 0):

> I never allocate any plate objects on the heap.

*vector* allocates on the heap.

Just *trust* valgrind. The line he complaining about allocates memory which was never freed.

Comment: Hmmm. Interesting. I didn't know it did that. But wouldn't vector automatically destruct those elements. I mean, that's one of the most attractive features of a vector. Or so I thought..

Comment: Only of the vector is destructed. Do you free all the `hanoi_object`s?